# Use setSeconds(); to close my splash screen in blackberry cascade

Tags: blackberry, time, blackberry-10, cascade

Well, Here I have a screen which I want to get close after 2-3 Seconds. For that I am using setDate() method.

I am very new to this Blackberry Cascade QML programming. I want to attach 1 more splash screen, so for that reason I want to use timer to close and open the sheet according to seconds.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I have worked on the following code.

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import bb.cascades.pickers 1.0

Page
{
Container 
{
  background: Color.Transparent
    //Todo: fill me with QML
    onCreationCompleted: 
    {
        mysheet1.open();
        new Date();

        **Error is shown in for loop**
        for(Date.setSeconds(1),Date.setSeconds()<=5 , Date.setSeconds()+1)
        {

           if(Date == 5)
           {
            mysheet1.closed();
            mysheet2.open();
           }
        }
     }

    attachedObjects: 
    [
      Sheet 
      {
        id: mysheet1
        peekEnabled: false

        Page 
        {
            Container 
            {
                background: Color.Transparent


                ImageView 
                {
                    horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
                    verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
                    imageSource: "asset:///splash1.png"

                }

            }

        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Context Invokable: Date Date(...)

The Date object is used to work with dates and times.
Date objects are created with the new Date() constructor.
There are four ways of initiating a date:
new Date() // current date and time (or)
new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01 (or)
new Date(dateString) (or)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

Invokable: number setSeconds(number sec)

Sets the seconds of a date object.

Answer (score 0):

It will use a lot of process for some seconds. But there is no setInterval in QML.
The best solution is using a C++ class, TimeManager.cpp with a QTimer:

To expose the C++ method to QML you can register as a ContextProperty when the QML is instanciated:

```
QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(this);
qml->setContextProperty("TimeManager", new TimeManager());
```

And declare the method:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void callLater(int milliSeconds, QObject* sloter);
```

The implementation:

```
void TimeManager::callLater(int milliSeconds, QObject* sloter){
     QTimer::singleShot(milliSeconds, sloter, SLOT(timerEnd()));
}
```

And the QML:

```
onCreationCompleted: {
    TimeManager.callLater(2500, this);
}

onTimerEnd: {
mysheet1.closed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code of Timer.

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import my.timer 1.0
Page {
    Container {
        layout: DockLayout {
        }
        onCreationCompleted: {
            mTimer.start();
        }
        ImageView {
            id: mImageViewIcon
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
            imageSource: "asset:///images/splash.png"
        }
        attachedObjects: [
            QTimer {
                id: mTimer
                interval: 2000
                onTimeout: {
                    //Push New Page here
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Don't forgot to add below line in main.cpp

```
qmlRegisterType<QTimer>("my.timer", 1, 0, "QTimer");
```